# What is the reason for this usage error using sockaddr_in() in Perl?

Tags: perl, sockets, debugging

This problem almost drove me crazy (running in Perl debugger):

```
  DB<3> x sockaddr_in(123, inet_aton('localhost'))
usage:   (port,iaddr) = sockaddr_in(sin_sv) at (eval 7)[/usr/lib/perl5/5.18.2/perl5db.pl:732] line 2.
```

However:

```
  DB<10> x $a = sockaddr_in(123, inet_aton('localhost'))
0  "\cB\c@\c@{\c?\c@\c@\cA\c@\c@\c@\c@\c@\c@\c@\c@"
```

This is the only example I know where I cannot print the result of a function call in the Perl debugger directly (but only after having it assigned to a variable).

Also this is the only function I know that outputs a usage error when being called with correct parameters.

Who can explain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not an issue with the debugger, it is a warning emitted by `sockaddr_in` when it is used with two arguments in list context.

```
$ perl -MSocket -wE 'say length(sockaddr_in(123,inet_aton("localhost")))'
16

$ perl -MSocket -wE 'say sockaddr_in(123,inet_aton("localhost"))'
usage:   (port,iaddr) = sockaddr_in(sin_sv) at -e line 1.
```

`sockaddr_in` has two calling syntaxes. It can convert an unpacked port and address into a packed socket address (converting a list of two elements to a scalar), or it can convert a packed socket address into a port and address (converting a scalar into a list of two elements).

```
$sockaddr = sockaddr_in($port,$ip_address);
($port,$ip_address) = sockaddr_in($sockaddr);
```

It can tell which operation is requested by the number of arguments passed to the function and by the context of the function call, and warns when the two are inconsistent.

Comment: So the bug is the error message text, it seems: "**List context expects just one parameter**" would be a better error message in that case (Showing the usage for one parameter, when two parameters are given and allowed, seems odd). I'm having trouble with Perl's inverted logic: The expected return type influences the number of parameters expected instead of the usual way (the number of parameters affects the return type). None of those is really pretty, but still I would prefer the argument-driven return type.

Comment: The dual use of `sockaddr_in` was confusing. The current docs for the `Socket` module recommend that you use `pack_sockaddr_in` and `unpack_sockaddr_in` to be explicit about which operation you want to apply.

Comment: Re "*The expected return type influences the number of parameters expected*", No. How it was called affects its function, just like basing the function on the number of parameters.